# Node pg pool.query not calling my callback

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I've been following the node-postgres docs to create a single file for all SQL calls. I'm using the pool.query for each call so that the module can manage the connections for me. [Link to docs](https://node-postgres.com/guides/project-structure)

My application has been working fine, but I've reached a point where I'm running into a pool.query call hanging without calling my callback. I'm performing the following operations:

1. INSERT one record
2. SELECT 25 records
3. INSERT 25 records (one call each)
4. UPDATE 25 records (one call each) <--- this is where it hangs.

I suspect that it's due to my pool.query calls, but I can't find anything in the documentation that helped.

Here is what I have so far:

db/client.js

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
// TODO: load default values from database.json (dev)
const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.PGUSER || "postgres",
    password: process.env.PGPASSWORD || "dev.123",
    host: process.env.PGHOST || "localhost",
    database: process.env.PGDATABASE || "dev",
    port: process.env.PGPORT || "5432"
});

const query = (text, params, callback) => {
    return pool.query(text, params, (err, res) => {
        if(err) {
            return callback(err.stack);
        }
        callback(null, res.rows);
    });
};

module.exports = { query };
```

db/postgres/card.js

```
const client = require('../client');

const updateOne = (cardDetails, callback) => {
    client.query('UPDATE cards SET color = $1, status = $2 WHERE id = $3', [cardDetails.color, cardDetails.status, cardDetails.id], (err, res) => {
        if(err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        callback(null, res);
    });
}
```

services/card.js

```
const CardModel = require('../models/card');
const Constants = require('../db/constants');

const updateColor = (cardDetails, color, callback) => {
    cardDetails.color = color;
    CardModel.updateOne(cardDetails, (err, res) => {
        if(err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        console.log(res);
        callback(null, res);
    });
}
```

services/game.js

```
const CardService = require('./card');
const Constants = require('../db/constants');

CardService.updateColor(cards[currIndex], Constants.Color.BLUE, (err, res) => updatedCards++);
```

I've tried debugging with VSCode and setting console.log's, but my callback in game.js is not being called.

EDIT:

I followed Bergi's advice with managing the pool manually, but I'm still seeing the same issue. Here is the new code for db/client.js:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');

// TODO: load default values from database.json (dev)
const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.PGUSER || "postgres",
    password: process.env.PGPASSWORD || "dev.123",
    host: process.env.PGHOST || "localhost",
    database: process.env.PGDATABASE || "dev",
    port: process.env.PGPORT || "5432"
});

pool.on('error', (err, client) => {
    console.error('Unexpected error on idle client', err);
    process.exit(-1);
});

const query = (text, params, callback) => {
    pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
        if(err) {
            return callback(err.stack);
        }

        client.query(text, params, (err, res) => {
            done();
            if(err) {
                return callback(err.stack);
            }
            callback(null, res.rows);
        });
    });
};

module.exports = { query };
```

models/card.js:

```
const CardDB = require('../db/postgres/card');

const findByGameIndex = (gameId, index, callback) => CardDB.findByGameIndex(gameId, index, callback);

const createOne = (cardDetails, callback) => CardDB.createOne(cardDetails, callback);

const updateOne = (cardDetails, callback) => CardDB.updateOne(cardDetails, callback);

module.exports = { findByGameIndex, createOne, updateOne };
```

Comment: Don't use `pool.query` for multiple queries. [Acquire a client from the pool, use it multiple times, then release it](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling/).

Comment: Is this your whole code? Where are the 25 calls? What logs *do* you get? How do you start this program? Is `/models/card` the same as `/db/postgres/card`?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was thinking about doing that, but it seems tricky with my project structure. In short, I have a service layer, models and the client call (which calls pg's pool.query right now). In theory, I'm running model.createOne and model.updateOne commands to update records in the DB. Would it be overkill to acquire the client from the pool, use it once and then release it?

Comment: /models/card is simply calling the /db/postgres/card for now. I want to make it so that it can be easily reconfigured to use another DB backend. I've updated my question with a new pool handling code that has the same results.

Comment: @user2714286 please don't add answers to questions. I have removed it and added it as an answer. Please edit that answer and add the content from the links here itself.

Comment: @Yatin sorry about that. I've updated the answer with the relevant content.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

<sub>(Reposting solution on behalf of the question author, to move it to the answer space.)</sub>

The original query code was fine. The issue was somewhere else in my
code that was causing the connection to remain idle (an infinite while
loop!). For anyone running into similar issues, please look at my code
and the pg-pool github page:

https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/tree/master/packages/pg-pool
(look under "your new favorite helper method"):

```
var pool = new Pool()
pool.query('SELECT $1::text as name', ['brianc'], function (err, res) {
  console.log(res.rows[0].name) // brianc
})
```

> pro tip: unless you need to run a transaction (which requires a single client for multiple queries) or you have some other edge case like streaming rows or using a cursor you should almost always just use pool.query. Its easy, it does the right thing ™️, and wont ever forget to return clients back to the pool after the query is done.